# how to setup 'hostname fqdn' on a VPS

Tags: email, vps, hostname, fqdn

I recently bought a vps server with DirectAdmin installed on it. everything works fine except I can't send emails.
the DirectAdmin's messaging system issued this notification:

> Cannot find your hostname using the command '/bin/hostname --fqdn'. Please check this >command to ensure it works properly.
>   If you get the error:
>   hostname: Name or service not known
>
> Check your /etc/resolv.conf and try setting it to use 127.0.0.1Unable to resolve your >hostname, .  This will cause major issues when sending email.
>
> Solution:
>
> Create an A record for your hostname (.) in your DNS control panel. Point the hostname to >your server's main IP address.  Also check /etc/hosts to ensure that the server ip is >correctly set.

my /etc/hosts contains this:

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs  
# that require network functionality will fail.  
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost  
127.0.1.1   srvubu100.screweb.com   srvubu100      ::1     localhost ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1   ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters  

178.162.145.82      srv771.screweb.com  
178.162.145.82      srv771.bitcommand.com  
178.162.145.82      server1.novinhost.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a hostname using the script `/usr/local/directadmin/scripts/hostname.sh` like this:

```
/usr/local/directadmin/scripts/hostname.sh host.yourdomain.com
```

Then you should edit your `/etc/hosts` file and leave it like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost

178.162.145.82 host.yourdomain.com
```

Then restart your exim (`service exim restart`) and it should work ok.